# Incorrect number of USB ports displayed with dmidecode

Tags: usb, hardware

I'm trying to find the number of USB port in my system.
So I've used `dmidecode` command like given below,

```
$ dmidecode -t 8 | grep 'USB'
```

The command shows 5 USB ports details like below,

```
External Reference Designator: USB
External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
Port Type: USB
External Reference Designator: USB
External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
Port Type: USB
External Reference Designator: USB
External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
Port Type: USB
External Reference Designator: USB
External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
Port Type: USB
External Reference Designator: USB
External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
Port Type: USB
```

But, My system have only 3 ports. 
How it shows 5 details? Is there any other command to find that?

Thank you.

Comment: I have only built-in web cam.

Answer (score 1):

According to your PC model as given in a comment (Lenovo G585), we can conclude that this is a laptop which has an integrated webcam.

While your computer only has three external USB ports, the other two are used for internal things, such as the webcam and perhaps another device on your computer (my guess is your SD card reader). To the system, this is still technically a USB "port", although it's not available for your use. You can identify what these internal devices are by using `lsusb`.